# Wordpress Front end form to upload document .doc or .pdf

Tags: forms, wordpress, upload

Just wondering if there is a plugin that you are aware of that i can find that will allow anyone can go to a form that supports document uploads etc.

I pretty much want to allow people to go to the site, see a job vacancy and apply for it by entering the details and being able to upload their resume.

Thanks for your help guys, im finding it hard to find a plugin anywhere that is free as im on a low budget.

Thanks again

Comment: Did neither of those answers work?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options here. Either allow a contributor to upload files with an addition to the functions. This would let them upload things from their Dashboard;
http://wpcanyon.com/tipsandtricks/allow-contributors-to-upload-files-in-wordpress/

Or something a little more suited to photos, but something you could certainly use quite well with NextGEN gallery; http://wpmu.org/how-to-add-a-smooth-jquery-public-file-uploader-to-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

TDO Mini Forms allows you to do exactly what your asking, and it's free.

http://thedeadone.net/download/tdo-mini-forms-wordpress-plugin/

The only downside is that it is no longer supported, so you're pretty much on your own if you have problems. What you're asking for seems pretty straightforward, though.

Another option is Wufoo: http://wufoo.com/

It is a fantastic service, and meshes beautifully with WP. The downside is that while they have a free plan, the file upload component is only part of the paid plan.

Hope that helps!